# Scraping with changing xpaths: Setting text pattern as ID?

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape the same info from a number of websites. The problem is that the number of elements changes among the sites. Which makes it impossible to use xpath or full xpath.
However, one line of text input is always the same; from which I want the number to be scraped

```
<div class="txt-block">
<h4 class="inline">Points for this match</h4> 33  </div>
```

How can I use "Points for this match" as ID in order to scrape "33"

Thanks for any leads!

Comment: Please could you share a couple of website urls for testing? There may be a better way than xpath (maybe not, but maybe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the '[node, contains()]' parameter.
Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

html_obj <- read_html(x = 
'<div class="txt-block">
 <h4 class="inline">Points for this match</h4> 33  </div>') 

html_nodes(x = html_obj,
           xpath = '//div[contains(h4, "Points for this match")]') %>% 
  html_text( trim  = TRUE) %>% 
  gsub("^Points for this match ", "", . )
```